# Decompose (as well as can) some number using predefined set of numbers with fixed set of coefficient

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I got a strange task: I need to decompose some number using linear combination of $3$ numbers, chosen from some predefined set (It's size is bigger). Also coefficients of such linear combination should be plus-minus powers of $2.$ Is there any way to implement in?

Comment: Depending on specifics it could be impossible.  For instance, $5$, being odd, cannot be written as such a "combination" of the numbers $2,4,6,8,10$ as any such combination would be even.

Answer (score 0):

So you have three unknowns (call them $a, b, c$), all powers of 2, and one equation, $s = a \cdot n_1 + b n_2 + c n_3$. First divide out any common powers of 2. Then, if $s$ is odd, and just one of $n_1, n_2, n_3$ is odd, it is clear that it's coefficient must be $2^0 = 1$. You can break down other cases similarly.

The resulting equation doesn't look like something solvable easily. You'd have to search for solutions.